# Forwarding error with Spring Cloud Zuul

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, netflix-ribbon

I'm using Eureka as a registry server where Zuul is being registered registered additionally to my application module cmpnyhbaseserialser.

However, when I make a POST request I get the following error:

```
Forwarding error
com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.handleException(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:164) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:139) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.run(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:84) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
        at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:112) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
        at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:193) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
        at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:157) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
        at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.route(FilterProcessor.java:118) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
        at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.route(ZuulRunner.java:96) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
        at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.route(ZuulServlet.java:116) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
        at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:81) ~[zuul-core-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:157) [spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController.handleRequest(ZuulController.java:44) [spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50) [spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) [spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) [spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:105) [spring-boot-actuator-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:107) [spring-boot-actuator-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_17]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_17]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0_17]
    Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: null
        at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:123) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
        at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:81) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.support.AbstractRibbonCommand.run(AbstractRibbonCommand.java:96) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.support.AbstractRibbonCommand.run(AbstractRibbonCommand.java:42) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
        at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:301) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.6.jar:1.5.6]
        at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:297) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.6.jar:1.5.6]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:46) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10307) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10274) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.BlockingOperatorToFuture.toFuture(BlockingOperatorToFuture.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.toFuture(BlockingObservable.java:412) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.queue(HystrixCommand.java:377) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.6.jar:1.5.6]
        at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.execute(HystrixCommand.java:343) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.6.jar:1.5.6]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:133) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
        ... 67 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at rx.exceptions.Exceptions.propagate(Exceptions.java:58) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:465) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.single(BlockingObservable.java:342) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:102) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
        ... 130 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_17]
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150) ~[na:1.7.0_17]
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121) ~[na:1.7.0_17]
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137) ~[httpcore-4.4.5.jar:4.4.5]
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153) ~[httpcore-4.4.5.jar:4.4.5]
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:282) ~[httpcore-4.4.5.jar:4.4.5]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259) ~[httpcore-4.4.5.jar:4.4.5]
        at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163) ~[httpcore-4.4.5.jar:4.4.5]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:167) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273) ~[httpcore-4.4.5.jar:4.4.5]
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125) ~[httpcore-4.4.5.jar:4.4.5]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:271) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.apache.RibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient.execute(RibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient.java:101) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.apache.RibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient.execute(RibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient.java:41) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
        at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient$1.call(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:109) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
        at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$3$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:303) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
        at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$3$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:287) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
        at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$3.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:231) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$3.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:228) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap$ConcatMapSubscriber.drain(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:286) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap$ConcatMapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:144) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
```

Comment: That's not enough information to help.

Answer (score 2):

Beware that ribbon is not the default http client for Zuul anymore. So you have to add `ribbon.restclient.enabled=true` to make ribbon config work.

> The default HTTP client used by zuul is now backed by the Apache HTTP Client instead of the deprecated Ribbon RestClient. To use RestClient or to use the okhttp3.OkHttpClient set ribbon.restclient.enabled=true or ribbon.okhttp.enabled=true respectively.

Answer (score 1):

It could be the hystrix timeout as Nikhil Pareek suggests or the ribbon timeouts or both. Best try:

```
hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        isolation:
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 10000
ribbon:
  ConnectTimeout: 10000
  ReadTimeout: 10000
```

I'd suggest both as the stacktrace matches [com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error while calling microservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49777627/com-netflix-zuul-exception-zuulexception-forwarding-error-while-calling-microse/50139518#50139518) and in that case the hystrix timeout was already set.

Comment: Make sure to look in the logs, if you also set Zuul host timeouts then the combination of Ribbon and Connect Timeouts may exceed Hystrix.

Answer (score 0):

Just increase hystrix timeout

```
hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        isolation:
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 10000
```